# Woocommerce Authorize.net DPM relay timeout error since upgrade

Tags: woocommerce, authorize.net

When attempting to process a credit card with Woocommerce Authorize.net DPM plugin, the browser does not redirect after processing through the gateway. Instead it is "stuck" in the gateway and echoes the following message below. It has only been happening since we upgraded Woocommerce. We have version 2.1.12 and version 1.5.0 of the Woocommerce authorize.net DPM. I have tried disabling other plugins while checking out, no errors in the error log, making sure no values are in the relay urls on the account, etc. I'm pulling my hair out! Please help if you know what could be going on!

[image]

> An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the
>   merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of
>   the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your
>   credit card.
>
> ```
>   This transaction has been approved. It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the product or
> ```
>
> service.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue recently, caused by our security plugin (iThemes, in this case) blocking requests with no user agents. I think this block may have come about in a recent update as I was able to resolve my issue by disabling the *HackRepair.com's blacklist feature*. If in fact this is your problem, you'd be looking for a line in your htaccess that looks similar to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Relay Response error. As noted [here](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/5-Most-Common-Errors/ba-p/35655), this means that "that Authorize.Net is unable to connect to the page that you have specified as your relay response URL".

According to [Woocommerce's article](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/authorize-net-dpm/) about troubleshooting common problems with the authorize.net DPM payment gateway, a good place to start is by deactivating nonessential plugins to see if there is a conflict.

As I just learned from encountering this problem, another possible cause for this (somewhat vague) error message is an empty MD5 field in the woocommerce settings if an MD5 Hash Value has been set for the merchant. You can check or set the MD5 hash value in authorize.net by going to Account > Settings > Security Settings > MD5-Hash.

If no hash value has been set through authorize.net, that setting can be left blank. But if it has been set, leaving it blank will apparently produce a Relay Response error.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

I contacted woocommerce for this issue and it was resolved by changing to permalink setting for woocommerce to something other than default. You can change this setting in the Settings > Permalink page at the bottom.